# ZF2 dynamic collection validators

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, zend-form, zend-filter

I've tried to add a dynamic validator to a collection but everything I've tried hasn't worked.

If I have - let's say - 3 fieldsets in a collection, I only want the second fieldset (with name "1") to have a required field.

```js
$input_filter = new Filter\Edit();
$collection_input_filter = new CollectionInputFilter();

$orderDetailFilter = new Filter\OrderDetail($serviceManager);
$collection_input_filter->setInputFilter($orderDetailFilter);

$input_filter->add($collection_input_filter, 'details');

$this->setInputFilter($input_filter)
    ->setHydrator(new DoctrineHydrator($entityManager))
    ->setObject(new Order());
```

Comment: No, i don't think you can do it. Since the input filter for the fieldsets is the same instance.

Comment: i can iterate for fieldset after the form is bind with entity object and before form is validated, i can set for each validation group or add new validator but does not take into account. this is not a good think if you have a one to many form, in the many part object can have diferent requirements

Comment: Try to print the object id of the input filter for each fieldset. It would print the same object id, so if you attach different validators it would modify the same object again and again, so it will not take effect.

Comment: so this can be a feature for zf2 validators in the future? anyway i still wait for solution maybe somebody make a hack or something.

Answer (score 0):

Check this:
http://www.aronkerr.com/2013/11/zf2-form-collection-validation-unique.html
He adding unique values for an element in a fieldset collection. He extend the InputCollectionFilter. 
You can do the same way for your custom key validation.

You have to extend the isValid Method from the CollectionInputFilter.
Write your own CollectionInputFilter and extend it from the Zend\InputFilter\CollectionInputFilter.

Add your own property:

```
protected validateFieldsetKeys = array()
```

for Example 
with a setter Method.

When you´re adding your CollectionInputfilter (in your factory or controller), just call your own and add your fieldsetkeys like this:

```
$collection_input_filter = new CollectionInputFilter();
$collection_input_filter->setValidateFieldsetKeys(array(2,3));
```